# How to get COUNT query in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

To get a query in django I can do:

```
>>> print User.objects.all().query
SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`last_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.`is_active`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`date_joined` 
FROM `auth_user`
```

However, how would I get the query it builds when doing a COUNT?

```
>>> User.objects.all().count().query
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'query'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count)

> **count()**
>
> Returns an **integer** representing the number of objects in the database matching the QuerySet.

Thus, you **can't.**

However, you can make use of [`django.db.connection.queries`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) in order to see and access the queries that are made by the current process.

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> User.objects.count()
>>> print connection.queries
```

Note that, this works only when `DEBUG=True` and you can't access them from another process, you can't share between views.

The best option would be to use the [Django debug toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar).

Comment: I understand that. Is there a way to see the query that django generates to get the count though?

Answer (score 4):

`CaptureQueriesContext` will grab the query for you after it's run, and I think works without `DEBUG`:

```
from django.test.utils import CaptureQueriesContext
from django.db import connection

with CaptureQueriesContext(connection) as queries:
    value = User.objects.count()
    print(queries.captured_queries[0]['sql'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If DEBUG is on, you can always get the queries executed by Django from the connection object, as described [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the query, simply install the Django Debug Toolbar: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar