# Django DRF incorrect pagination count

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

I use a custom yet simple pagination class for my django drf application:

```py
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = "page_size"
    max_page_size = 100
```

I have also a ViewSet action that does some operation on the inherited queryset and return the result paginated:

```py
class MatchOfJobViewSet(ModelViewSet):

  serializer_class = MatchSerializer
  filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)

  # classic filter inheriting from django_filter.FilterSet
  filter_class = MatchFilter

  def get_queryset(self):
    job_pk = self.kwargs["job_pk"]
    return Match.objects.filter(job_pk=job_pk)

  @action(
    detail=False,
    methods=["get"],
    url_path="dynamic",
    serializer_class=MatchDynamicSerializer
  )
  def dynamic(self, request, *args, other_args, **kwargs):
    """return the list of matches with a dynamic serializer"""

    # some operation on the queryset
    queryset = self.get_queryset().select_related("some_field")

    # apply the filters
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)

    # paginate
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

    # I use a custom serializer that takes extra arguments
    # to update dynamically the fields to be serialized
    serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True, other_args=other_args)

    # unchanged from the generic list response
    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

The response I get from the view is like this

```json
{
  "count": 308,
  "next": "https://blabla.com?page=2&page_size=100",
  "previous": "https://blabla.com?page=4&page_size=100",
  "results": [...]
}
```

The count indicates 308 entries **although there are only 297 entries when I check in the database** (which causes the last page to end up empty)

From what I read the `count` parameter is computed by the Paginator (which is the default *DjangoPaginator*) by using the same queryset. How can the evaluated queryset and the Paginator.count() give different results?

Comment: In the table it may be `297` rows, that doesn't mean that the `QuerySet.count()` in the pagination class must return the same number. That is, your QuerySet may contain some duplicate rows.

Comment: I can see you have been using the `filter_backends`, which may cause the duplication, somehow

Comment: Show us the `MatchFilter`, I believe something happens there. Like filtering many to many relationships and getting multiple duplicate results.

Comment: This is true, the filters might duplicate the entries. I will check if adding distinct(id) changes anything. However it there was duplicate rows the last page wouldn't be empty, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment I found that the discrepancy between `queryset.count()` and `len(queryset)` where caused by some annotations applied in my `get_queryset()` method.

I thought using `queryset.query.annotations.clean()` would totally clean it from the SQL query but it left some traces, notably some OUTTER LEFT JOIN. This resulted into entries counted multiple times by the COUNT SQL query.

If you end up having similar issues, I'd recommend to double check the filters and annotation applied to your queryset. You can inspect the SQL query run by `.count()` using the method from [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652584/how-to-get-count-query-in-django)